# Does the Catholic Church accept all the teachings of the Byzantine Church after the union?

Tags: catholicism

Late Pope John Paul II said, "Byzantine Church is the other lung of Catholic Church."

Does this mean these two churches are united together now?

Does the Catholic Church, the bride of Jesus (according to the Catechism of the Catholic Church), accept all the teachings of the Byzantine Church?

Answer (score 2):

**Does the Catholic Church accept all the teachings of the Byzantine Church after the union?**

Allow me to clarify something first. Very few of those of the Eastern Orthodox Churches have united back to Rome. Those that have reunited had to accept the teachings of the Roman Catholic Church and not the other way around.

Pope St. John Paul II mentioned the Church praying with two lungs, symbolizing the Churches of the East and the West.

Pope John Paul II wrote 14 encyclicals. One of these dealt with the subject matter of the commitment to ecumenism and the restoration of Christian unity. [***Ut Unum Sint***](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_25051995_ut-unum-sint.html) makes reference to the Church’s desire to breathe with two lungs. Obviously, the Byzantine Church as a whole is no where near being completely united to Rome. The (Roman) Church's desire for such unity is ever present and desired.

Thus until full unity of all the Orthodox Churches with Rome, the Church as one body in Christ cannot truly breathe with both her lungs!

> 54. The other event which I am pleased to recall is the celebration of the Millennium of the Baptism of Rus' (988-1988). The Catholic Church, and this Apostolic See in particular, desired to take part in the Jubilee celebrations and also sought to emphasize that the Baptism conferred on Saint Vladimir in Kiev was a key event in the evangelization of the world. The great Slav nations of Eastern Europe owe their faith to this event, as do the peoples living beyond the Ural Mountains and as far as Alaska.
>
> **In this perspective an expression which I have frequently employed finds its deepest meaning: the Church must breathe with her two lungs!** In the first millennium of the history of Christianity, this expression refers primarily to the relationship between Byzantium and Rome. From the time of the Baptism of Rus' it comes to have an even wider application: evangelization spread to a much vaster area, so that it now includes the entire Church. If we then consider that the salvific event which took place on the banks of the Dnieper goes back to a time when the Church in the East and the Church in the West were not divided, we understand clearly that the vision of the full communion to be sought is that of unity in legitimate diversity. This is what I strongly asserted in my Encyclical Epistle Slavorum Apostoli 85 on Saints Cyril and Methodius and in my Apostolic Letter Euntes in Mundum 86 addressed to the faithful of the Catholic Church in commemoration of the Millennium of the Baptism of Kievan Rus'. - [Ut Unum Sint](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_25051995_ut-unum-sint.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, I would ask for clarification, but the quetion's author appears no longer to have an active account. Therefore, we will consider two different answers depending on what is meant, precisely, by "Byzantine Church."

On the one hand, "Byzantine Church" could refer to the Orthodox Churches in schism from Rome who still practice Byzantine Liturgies, such as the Liturgy of St. John Chrysostom. The Catholic Church *does not* accept all the teachings of these churches, because these churches teach that certain Catholic dogmas are heresies.

One example is the doctrine of Papal Supremacy. [Here is an Orthodox article](http://orthodoxinfo.com/inquirers/papal_supremacy.aspx) making an argument against this dogma of the Catholic Church (defined at the first Vatican Council).

On the other hand, "Byzantine Church" could refer to the Eastern Christians in full communion with Rome. These churches (usually) were once separated after the schism of 1054, but have returned to the barque of Peter. As such, *they* have renounced anything which is contrary to the *Catholic* faith, and not the other way around.